# [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' using parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to implement parse push notification. However I get an error in the main saying `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

Is there something that I am doing wrong in the viewdidload of App delegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
    // Enable Crash Reporting
    [ParseCrashReporting enable];


    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@""
                  clientKey:@""];


    RVConfig *config = [RVConfig defaultConfig];
    config.applicationToken = @"<>";
    [config addBeaconUUID:@"<"];

    Rover *rover = [Rover setup:config];
    [rover startMonitoring];

    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}




- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if ([[Rover shared] handleDidReceiveLocalNotification:notification]) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I may be missing something and this is my first time implementing push using parse in objective-c. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method return statement should be in last line.

Comment: You should set [Parse setApplicationId:@"" clientKey:@""] these values. It cannot be empty.

Comment: Roy I have those values did not show it for security reasons

Comment: I have it in the last line and still crashes

Comment: Have you checked the RVConfig and Rover class for errors yet? Just an assumption but it might be the case that the exception gets thrown from there

Comment: Set a breakpoint and find out exactly what line causes the crash